# Why I can not use virtual hostname to get my micro service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a provider in my eureka, like this:

[image]

Then I use `restTemplate` to get the the message, like this:

```
  @Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@RequestMapping("getInfo")
public String getMessage(){
    return restTemplate.getForObject("http://microservice_provider/user/getUserInfo", String.class);
}

@LoadBalanced
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate()
{
    return new RestTemplate();

}
```

}

But it never does works. It tells me:

[image]

So, what can I do to use like this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `RestTemplate` bean and annotate you bean with `@LoadBalanced`.

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
public RestTemplate loadBalancedRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

That way, you can use the name of the microservice `microservice_provider` as part of the url.

```
String remotemsg = restTemplate.getForObject("http://microservice_provider/user/getInfo",String.class);
```

Comment: I am sorry,but I used that in fact, I forgot to show you ,and it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Kindly update you question by posting the full stacktrace.

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace so that we can see where the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In the url `"http://microservice_provider"` the hostname `microservice_provider` is not a valid hostname since underscore `_` isn't valid in hostnames. Change the name and it will work. There has been a recent change to fix the NPE with a clear error message.